# How to stream audio from my pc to an iphone via an URL (not using apps)

Tags: streaming

I saw some sites who give you a link that when you access it from your iphone you can hear audio stream, how can i do that from my server? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Winamp SHOUTcast DSP for instance, to broadcast whatever you are playing back on your Winamp over the lan.

> Use Winamp media player along with the
>   SHOUTcast DSP plug-in to program and
>   manage your SHOUTcast station in
>   real-time. This plug-in will broadcast
>   whatever is playing in your Winamp
>   playlist in real time. Use Winamp's
>   industry-leading playlist tools to
>   manage your SHOUTcast station.

[Link](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools)